# When voting to close a question because it belongs on another SE site, why is ham.meta.SE the only choice?

Tags: discussion, status-bydesign, moderation, migration, vote-to-close

I just tried to vote to close a question because it belongs on another SE site, in my opinion.  When trying to vote I was forced to designate the other SE site that I think the question belongs in, but the only available choice was ham.meta.SE, but that's not the site that I had in mind.

Is this something that the moderators control?  If so, then I respectfully suggest that the moderators give us a few more options.  If not, then it feels like a bug...

(For the record, the other site that I had in mind was electronics.SE.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apparently the feature to set up migration paths is not available to "beta" sites (found in [a footnote in this discussion of migration](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/10250)).

Comment: Well, now we know.  Thanks for researching that one Kevin.

Comment: Ah yes. [There's a lot of questions here in meta tagged *beta*](https://ham.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/beta).

Answer (score 1):

I didn't know that, Rob. If there is a way for a mod to change this, I am not aware of it.

However, before we migrate a question, we usually ask permission first in the site's chat room. I did that a few days ago [on this question](https://ham.stackexchange.com/q/18751/8717) (also in chat.electronics.SE), but nobody said okay. And there were not enough flags, etc. by others to close it.

However, a regular on that site posted an answer to it.

Comment: I didn't close it immediately as off-topic, because he is a new user.

Comment: Great, I learned something.  No worries about not migrating it right away, that would be rude.  But given that it's been three days, I had no trouble with the idea of migrating the question though ;)

Comment: @rclocher3 If you accept Kevin's answer, then the community bot won't regularly bring it to the top. And a *status-completed* and/or *status-by-design* tag can be added to your question.

Comment: Right, done, thanks for the reminder @MikeWaters, I'd forgotten to accept an answer.